# Apache Archiva for maven pom project

Tags: maven, repository, archiva

I've implemented Apache Archiva on my server and it runs on jetty *(localhost:8888)*. I've adding my jar and now I've one internal repo **(localhost:8888/repository/internal/)**. Well, now I need to integrate this repo into my project, and I've added it into repositories section of my pom.xml but I can't retrieve any of my loaded jar. I've reindexed external repositories into *Maven Repositories* view of eclipse and I've checked ***Enable Full Index*** for my repo and when I try to go into this repo, through this view, this location is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify how you added your JARs? If you added them to the filesystem, they need to be scanned (which is a scheduled job). If you added them through the Upload form they should have been indexed immediately (this also happens for artifacts proxied from a remote location or those deployed by Maven). The index file should not be relevant in this case.

Comment: what version of Archiva are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Latest version of **Archiva** You can add jars manually and it will show you all the added jar in Browse section.